# Zebra datepicker icon not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Anyone familiar with [Zebra Datepicker](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/)?

I can't seem to get the calendar icon to show up.

http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/gzbqrxpL/

I'm also trying:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

     <title>Untitled Document</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="zebra_datepicker.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css" type="text/css">

     <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {

             // assuming the controls you want to attach the plugin to 
             // have the "datepicker" class set
             $('datepickertest').Zebra_DatePicker();

         });
     </script>

</head>

<body>

     <form>

          <input type="text" id="datepickertest" class="datepicker" />

     </form>

</body>
</html>
```

With all those files local in the same directory, including calendar.png, the icon image.

In both cases the calendar icon doesn't show up.

Incidentally, I tried looking at the source of the demo page, and I don't see the scripts referred to anywhere, so that doesn't provide much guidance.

Comment: You've got all kinds of javascript errors on the page, that won't help.

Comment: Can you be speciic? I've been doing some edits. Does it look better now?

Comment: $('#datepickertest').Zebra_DatePicker(); At least this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example, based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/gzbqrxpL/1/

You should follow their tutorial.

First, add `<!doctype html>` at the beginning of you html file.

Second, download the script with ALL files, including the /css folder with themes.png, calendar.png, and the folder metallic if you want to use that theme.

Third, add jquery BEFORE adding the zebra datepicker.

It should then work. Your JSFiddle was not working because you were refering the external sources to github, and github is not a CDN, so the browser was not loading.

That's it.

Comment: Your code was correct, but the files were not loading properly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing the icon in your jsfiddle example, or the popup calendar. Are you sure it is working for you?  I was trying to create a bare bones example. My real implementation has all those files and links -- which I've checked and checked. Also, I do have <!doctype html> and jquery first in my sample code above.

Comment: It is working for me. Check your browser. What is your browser?

Comment: I have just tested in all my three browsers.

Comment: I changed the linke to public folders on my own website. Still not working.

Comment: I just tried it with a cleared cache in FF and IE. Could it be that jsfiddle is able to resolve the link from your browser because of some local permissions? If you clear the cache and current logons, do you still see the icon?

Comment: You are missing a '#' for the object. 
Instead of $('datepickertest').Zebra_DatePicker(); use $('#datepickertest').Zebra_DatePicker();

Comment: If you want to get an object from its ID you MUST use "#" before the id name.

Comment: That was it! I missed the # in the example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are correctly selecting the datepickertest.  Include a "#" or "." beforehand to select id or class respectively.  I think not including those selects tag elements.

Without looking specifically at Zebra-Datepicker, I know, at least, for the regular datepicker that you have to initialize some values.

```
$("#id").datepicker({
   showOn: "button",
   buttonImage: "../images/myImage.png",
   buttonImageOnly: true,
   ...
 });
```

Check which values you need to initialize.

Comment: I copied that right from the example at http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/ under "How to Use"! I wonder if it's a mistake?